# Как в checkedListBox отметить следующий неотмеченный элемент?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как в checkedListBox программно отметить следующий элемент в коллекции?

Например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @defaultlocale загрузил изображение, вот так)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью [`GetItemChecked`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemchecked?view=netframework-4.8) можно определить индекс первого неотмеченного элемента, а затем отметить его с помощью [`SetItemChecked`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemchecked?view=netframework-4.8):

```
int uncheckedIndex = Enumerable
                            //пробегаемся по всем индексам
                            .Range(0, checkedListBox1.Items.Count)
                            //выбираем первый неотмеченный, или 0 если таковых нет. 
                            .FirstOrDefault(i => !checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i));
checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(uncheckedIndex, true);
```

Если все элементы уже отмечены, то `uncheckedIndex` примет значение 0 и повторно отметит превый элемент, что вроде не страшно.

Можно то же самое написать без LINQ:

```
int uncheckedIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    if (!checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
    {
        uncheckedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
if (uncheckedIndex < 0)
{
    return;
}
checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(uncheckedIndex, true);
```